# best way to filter array of objects returned by observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Looking for efficient way to pick only one item from the array of objects returned by observable from the following, and pass it down the stream:

```
const message = of(req.body).pipe(
  .....
  .....
  filter(resp => (resp.status === 200 && resp.statusText === 'OK')),
  myFilter(resp.data.values),
  // and then continue
  tap(value => console.log(value)),
  ....
  ....    
); //end of pipe


structure of resp.data.values -> 
    [{ id: '37', createTime: '2018-03-28T09:13:07.180434550Z', name: 'tmp1'},
     { id: '38', createTime: '2018-03-28T09:14:07.180434550Z', name: 'tmp2'},
     { id: '38', createTime: '2018-03-28T09:15:07.180434550Z', name: 'tmp3'}]
```

The code is written in TypeScript 2.8.1 with "rxjs": "5.5.8" as a backend function on node.

Comment: What's wrong with your implementation?

Comment: use rxjs map function and inside it use filter on arrays

Comment: So you want to return only one item from `values` or the entire `resp` with `resp.data.values` filtered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want one value, and do not need it in an array, then you can achieve that with the `map` operator and the `find` method of `Array`:

```
const message = of(req.body).pipe(
  .....
  .....
  filter(resp => (resp.status === 200 && resp.statusText === 'OK')),
  map(resp => resp.data.values.find(item => item.id === '38')),
  // and then continue
  tap(value => console.log(value)),
  ....
  ....    
); //end of pipe
```

Of course, I'm assuming you want to filter by `id`, but you could filter by whichever predicate you want.

Comment: this is correct and had to only change 'find' section to include 'any' resp.data.values.find((item: any) => item.id === '38')

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return only one value, you can use:

```
first(resp => (resp.status === 200 && resp.statusText === 'OK')),
```

in the pipe instead of

```
filter(resp => (resp.status === 200 && resp.statusText === 'OK')),
```

If you want to get a specific item, you can specify it more closely in the predicate function of the `first` operator.

Comment: OK, now I got, that you might want to get one of the values in data. For that you could flatten the collection, and after myFilter call mergeMap(response => response.data.values), and you can access values one by one